# Enzyme - Firing an event in an element that's passed as a prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm using Enzyme to test a React component that passes another component as a prop.

I need to test an event handler in the prop component but am having trouble working with Enzyme. I've tried simulating the event and manually .click()'ing. I'm using Jest for the main testing framework.

Also, `wrapper.find('MenuItem')` isn't able to find the prop component.

**MainComponent.js**

```
<MainComponent>
  <Dropdown
    overlay={
      <Menu >
        {menuItems.map((item, i) => <Menu.Item key={i} onClick={() => handleClick(item)}>{item}</Menu.Item>)}
        <Menu.Divider />
        <Menu.Item/>
      </Menu>}
  />
</MainComponent>
```

**MainComponent.test.js**

```
const mockHandleClick = jest.fn()
const wrapper = shallow(<MainComponent handleClick={mockHandleClick} menuItems=['tag'] />)

const dropdown = wrapper.find('Dropdown')
const menu = dropdown.prop('overlay')
const menuItem = menu.props.children[0][0] // the map is stored as an array in children

expect(menuItem.props.children).toEqual('tag') // passes

// None of these work
// menuItem.simulate('click')
// menuItem.click()
// menuItem.dispatchEvent('click')

expect(mockHandleClick).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
mockHandleClick.mockClear()
```

I think I might have a fundamental misunderstanding of the difference between an element retrieved with `.find()` and an element retrieved through `.props()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you access `dropdown.prop` you're getting React *elements* (think like the data structures that the JSX represents). These are not *components* that are rendered and mounted on the page. This is why something like simulating click DOM events won't work.

What you'll have to do instead is find the `onClick` prop of `menuItem` and call it:

```
menuItem.props.onClick()
```